# app-engine module in android studio

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, android-studio

Can I use Android Studio to develop an android app with a Python AppEngine module? (Basically an app-engine connection android project where the app engine module is written in Python.)

Comment: do you mean including the app engine module itself or just the android app?

Comment: I mean like this https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/add_module except with Python for the module instead of Java.